# Hiding of member function templates - Which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, clang

I wrote the following code that hiding of member function templates.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    template<int> void func()
    {
        std::cout<<"Function tamplate of A"<<std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : A 
{
    template<char> void func()
    {
        std::cout<<"Function tamplate of B"<<std::endl;
    }
    using A::func;
};

int main()
{
    B().func<0>();
}
```

This program working in in **Clang** compiler. [Live demo Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yHl9eb3mDqCesSPI)

But, **GCC** compiler give an ambiguity error.[Live demo GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7sUns0T8GOVoi0gz)

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:22:17: error: call of overloaded ‘func()’ is ambiguous
     B().func<0>();
```

So, Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Also, since you have `using A::func` you're not doing any hiding at all. Instead you have *both* templates functions in full view in the `B` class.

Comment: btw same error on gcc for : `template<int> test(){} template<char> test(){} int main() { test<0>(); }` . Actually same error no matter what value is passed

Comment: Could not reproduce on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bafd4790b94216f1).

Comment: Lastly, you forgot to save your code on rextester. The links you have now are the generic for each compiler.

Comment: @Ron strange, same gcc version, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34164635e522c61b) doesnt compile

Comment: @Ron gcc 7.x seems to compile OP's code, while gcc 6.x gives the error OP posted.

Comment: VS 2013 also compiles fine although showing error overload in IDE.

Comment: Interesting. I was trying to lookup the standard on this. But it only specifies that implicit conversions should happen on template arguments to make them fit the parameters. Nothing about ranking the conversions. Very interesting. Could be the basis for a defect report, if there isn't one already (or I missed something in the standard draft).

Comment: @MarekR No that's how you pass compile-time constants to templates as template arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've fixed links to point to Wandbox since you can control version of clang and gcc. [It compiles for gcc 7.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gHrLZW0zp4vpzNsg).

Comment: i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972679/overloading-based-on-non-type-template-parameter) especially T.C.s comment is worth reading

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding the example in the OP: as pointed out to me by [W.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769112/hiding-of-member-function-templates-not-working-on-gcc/46769854?noredirect=1#comment80487059_46769854), what matters here is that those are **member** function templates. You added a using declaration, which specifies ([[namespace.udecl]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/namespace.udecl#15)):

> When a using-declaration brings names from a base class into a derived
>   class scope, member functions and member function templates in the
>   derived class override and/or hide member functions and **member
>   function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base
>   class (rather than conflicting).**

Note how template parameters aren't accounted. And it is Clang that treated the code correctly by hiding the `int` version.

---

On the other hand if one examines the example [tobi303](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34164635e522c61b) suggested [under your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769112/hiding-of-member-function-templates-not-working-on-gcc/46769854?noredirect=1#comment80483811_46769112), GCC is kinda in the right. This simply isn't specified to be resolved somehow.

For one, there's [[temp.fct.spec]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.fct.spec#temp.arg.explicit-3):

> Trailing template arguments that can be deduced or
>   obtained from default template-arguments may be omitted from the list
>   of explicit template-arguments. [...] **In contexts where deduction is
>   done and fails, or in contexts where deduction is not done, if a
>   template argument list is specified and it, along with any default
>   template arguments, identifies a single function template
>   specialization, then the template-id is an lvalue for the function
>   template specialization**.

The text in bold indicates that your program is well-formed only if the template argument we give nominates a single specialization. And ostensibly, it doesn't, since according to [[temp.arg.nontype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.arg.nontype#1):

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression of the type of the
>     template-parameter;

And 0 fits both overloads as a converted constant expression. On account of there not being any ICS ranking for template arguments, this is ambiguous.

Comment: theoretically there is one thing more to take into consideration - if the using itself can't be ignored because there exists an overload for this name in the class...

Comment: @W.F. - I'm not sure I follow. How can a using declaration be ignored?

Comment: sorry for my poor choice of wording :) I meant the situation like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/olcRNDWuKq0qyu1o)

Comment: [example compiles since gcc 7.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gHrLZW0zp4vpzNsg), so gcc was right.

Comment: see: [\[namespace.udecl\]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#15)

Comment: @W.F. - Oh... now that's interesting. `this` also take part in overload resolution (to say it colloquially).

Comment: @W.F. - Regarding your qutoe, I find it suspicious that templates are omitted from the example. But it is interesting. I need to do some testing.

Comment: I'd say all the premises to hide the function given there are fulfilled... so `func` should actually be hidden

Comment: @W.F. - I'm not so sure. `func<char>` and `func<int>` are different overloads. Are the template parameter lists ignored? Or are they taken into account, like function parameters? I tend to say it's the latter.

Comment: @W.F. - Well, you certainly saved me an embarrassment :)

Comment: Should probably just delete the first half of your answer? It's a bit misleading.

Comment: @Barry - I think that half is interesting on its own due to how tobi modified the OP. I moved stuff around to make things more on point. The first half addresses the OP now, as it should. The second clarifies that it addresses tobi's change. Hopefully it's better.